# In Java how do I change or set a default printer

Tags: java, printing

I know how to get the list of available printers, I want users to be able to select from a  list and set that to the default for the session

Using Windows 7

I know that this is easily done I just want to create a simple java program 
a: To increase my knowledge
b: Teachers here are very adverse to playing with printing properties

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I couldn't find it in Google apart from a nonsensical manner. I thought that it would be easier to create and register on forum that i lurked for a year or more and ask for help from a programming user base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program works in Eclipse.

```
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;

import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

public class PrinterSetup 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = pjob.defaultPage();
        pjob.setPrintable(null, pf);

        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
          pjob.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much what i want i want to do.
However was hoping to be able to set the default printer without starting a print job. Can Java do this?

Comment: The generated dialog box in this program will let you setup printer, for more information, check out this link:   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html

Comment: Thanks mate, Was a little confused now I think I got the hang of it

Answer (score 2):

You know how to get list of all printers then you want set a default printer.

### ok this code will help you can Pass Name of printer which you want to set as default printer where "MYPRINTER" .replace it with name of printer.

```
PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Number of printers configured: " + printServices.length);
    for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
        System.out.println("Printer: " + printer.getName());
        if (printer.getName().equals("***MYPRINTER***")) {
            try {
                pj.setPrintService(printer);
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            }
        }
    }
```

---

Comment: what about the 3-asteriks symbols ? Is that mandatory?

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround to set the OS default printer. This one works for windows which basically executes a cmd command that sets the default printer before executing the print code:

```
Desktop desktop = null
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()
    desktop.print(file)
 }
```

Here's my function:

```
public static boolean setDefaultPrinter(String printerName) {
    String defaultPrinterSetter = "wmic printer where name='"+ printerName +"' call setdefaultprinter";
    try {
        setDefaultPrinterProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /C " + defaultPrinterSetter);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

All you need to do is pass the printer name to this function and it'll make it the default printer.

Here's a function that gets a list of all avaiable printer services:

```
public static ArrayList<PrintService> availablePrinters() {
    PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    ArrayList<PrintService> allServices = new ArrayList<>();

    for (PrintService myService : services) {
        allServices.add(myService);
    }
    return allServices;
}
```

And I'll assume you'd want to add a list in maybe a combobox or something for user to choose from. It should go something like this

```
    ArrayList<PrintService> availableServices = availablePrinters();
    System.out.println("All printers list:");
    for (PrintService myService : availableServices) {
        myCombo.getItems().add(myService.getName());
        System.out.println(myService.getName());
    }
```