# Select Printer Of Web User Using Java Applet

Tags: java, html, printing, applet, awt

I've been searching a solution for changing the default printer from a java applet (and more) without success.

What I need is to print with javascript's method print(), that prints only in default printer, so, before this, change the default printer to the target printer.

Is this possible? Is there any library to do something like "setDefaultPrinter" or similar?

NOTE: I am trying to print HTML page, rendered as the user sees it in the browser.

Comment: *"I've tried to print with Print Service API, but doesn´t work for me because i need to print html code"* Huh?  1) Which 'Print Service API' specifically? Link to the docs. 2) *"print html code"* a) HTML is not code, but mark-up. b) What DYM by *'print **html'***?  Print it rendered as the user might see it in a browser - rendered nicely, or print the raw text (along with the mark-up, styles and JS) that makes the HTML document?

Comment: @Andrew 
I mean print html page what users see

Comment: And the links to the 'print service' you refer to?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Jquery Print Element

Comment: @AndrewThompson you only interested in saying huh ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from [In Java how do I change or set a default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787662/in-java-how-do-i-change-or-set-a-default-printer)

Try this

```
PrinterJob pjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat pf = pjob.defaultPage();
        pjob.setPrintable(null, pf);

        if (pjob.printDialog()) {
          pjob.print();
        }
```