# Set default printer with Java?

Tags: java

I'm developing a Java web application (which will be running on a Windows machine) where there is a requirement for creating and automatically printing PDFs. I have the creation side sorted, and the following is working for printing to the default printer:

```
     Desktop desktop = null
     if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()
        desktop.print(file)
     }
```

But is there a means of actually setting the default printer from Java? The default printer may be changed by a user in another application and I have to guard against that.

[As regards the 'possible duplicate', no, that does not answer the question. The requirement here is for automatic printing without user intervention, and the earlier answer provided involves presenting a print dialog to the user.]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Java how do I change or set a default printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11787662/in-java-how-do-i-change-or-set-a-default-printer)

Comment: If another application changes the default printer, that probably means the user intended to do that.  Changing it back from your app doesn't seem very user-friendly.

Comment: when I worked with printers we had to call a `vbscript` from the Java code to change printer settings and do stuff. so no, you can't set the a printer. only find all printers and choose, like in davidxxx's answer

Comment: “The default printer may be changed by a user in another application and I have to guard against that.”  Why?  Who are you to decide what I, as a user, want my default printer to be?  Other applications can function properly while other applications are running;  why can’t yours?

Comment: Wow, two comments questioning the ethics of what I'm doing! That's kind of weird, as you cannot possibly know enough about the particular circumstances to make such judgments. As it happens, it's a server machine which no individual user is in charge of, running a number of applications under my administrative control. What I am doing is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot set the default printer defined in the OS settings but you can select the printer service to use to print a document.

```
PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
```

will return all printer services (physical as virtual printers) if you pass `null` and `null` as arguments.

> Locates print services capable of printing the specified DocFlavor.
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> **flavor** the flavor to print. If null, this constraint is not used.
>
> **attributes** attributes that the print service must support. If null this constraint is not used.
>
> **Returns**:
>
> array of matching `PrintService` objects representing print services
>   that support the specified flavor attributes. If no services match,
>   the array is zero-length.

Then iterate on it until you find the suitable printer and print your doc :

```
for (PrintService printer : printServices) {
    if (printer.getName().contains("myPrinterName")) {
       job = printer.createPrintJob();
       job.print(myDoc, attributes);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't actually have a requirement to set the default printer, except that the desktop.print() approach I have taken prints to the default printer. I'll look into createPrintJob(), maybe it'll be nearly as simple that way.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround to set the OS default printer. This one works for windows which basically executes a cmd command that sets the default printer before executing the print code:

```
Desktop desktop = null
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
desktop = Desktop.getDesktop()
    desktop.print(file)
 }
```

Here's my function:

```
public static boolean setDefaultPrinter(String printerName) {
    String defaultPrinterSetter = "wmic printer where name='"+ printerName +"' call setdefaultprinter";
    try {
        setDefaultPrinterProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start cmd.exe /C " + defaultPrinterSetter);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

All you need to do is pass the printer name to this function and it'll make it the default printer. You could use davidxxx's answer to get all available printers names.